# neo4j: Cypher LOAD CSV with uuid

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, uuid, load-csv

I am starting to work with LOAD CSV of Cypher for Neo4J to import larger csv-files into my DB. I would like to add to each imported node a unique ID (uuid) as a property.

My try was:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:..." AS csvLine
CREATE (c:Customer { uuid: {uuid}, name: csvLine[0], code: csvLine[1]})
```

Unfortunately I receive for each node the same UUID (although its a function that would normally generate the UUID new when called), it looks like the UUID is generated 1 time and then attached to each node while creating the node and parsing the csv-file.

Is there a way to generate a new UUID for each imported csv-line to mark the node?

Thanks for your hints from
Balael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure where you've seen that {uuid} is a function. 
It is just using whatever you pass in as an parameter "uuid".

You'd have to generate a uuid when creating your CSV. 
In cypher there is currently no `uuid()` function.

One workaround that you could do is:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:..." AS csvLine
CREATE (c:Customer { name: csvLine[0], code: csvLine[1]})
SET c.id = id(c)
```

Comment: you could also use tools like csvkit (http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/) to modify your csv before importing it to have an uuid.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for sheding some light here. Unfortunately there is no way to generate a UUID in the CSV as they come from a system I dont have access. I understood that UUID cannot generated each time when the node is created. Also the set-command is just repeating to add the same UUID to each node as even e.g. a uniqid() in PHP seems not be called more than once so only one UUID is assigned to every node - which is exactly the opposite of what I want to create - a unique identifier.Seems I need to run again after the CSV through each node that has been created and add a UUID node by node.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to loop through again and add a UUID without doing it one node at a time, maybe check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952884/neo4j-assign-unique-values-to-all-nodes-matching-query. Might get you started.

Comment: Hi Stefan, wow, thats a neat tool, thanks for sharing. I have meanwhile added a second loop into the code to stamp all imported nodes with a UUID - not beautiful but working. I will defintly have a look at csvkit!

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will dig into the thread and se eif I can adapt the idea to my needs.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the [GraphAware UUID Module](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid).

All you would have to do is drop the [framework jar](http://graphaware.com/downloads/graphaware-server-community-all-2.1.5.25.jar) and the [uuid module jar](http://graphaware.com/downloads/graphaware-uuid-2.1.5.25.7.jar) into the plugins directory, add the following 2 lines into neo4j.properties, and restart Neo4j.

```
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.1=com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper
```

Any new node (no matter how it is created) will automatically get a UUID.

Comment: Hey Michal, thanks for your response, this works well. Do you know some resources on how one would build this from source? I am not familiar with the Java build ecosystem.

Comment: After cloning the project from GIT ( git clone https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid.git ), install the Java build tool named Maven. Depending on your environment macosx : "brew install maven", ubuntu/debian & co : "apt-get install maven". Then you can "cd  neo4j-uuid" then "mvn clean install" from the command line. The compiled build will reside in the "target/" directory of the project you cloned. PS. This may take a long time as all unit tests will be launched and all project dependencies will be downloaded.